# Compiling static library inside a static library -- issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, static-libraries

I created a static library which internally contains another static library (X) inside "Link Binary With Libraries" folder. But when I export my library to a sample project and try to compile it fails to locate the X library path. I am adding "." in the "Library search path" build parameter while building my static library.

What is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your issue correctly, then it is less a linker-search-path problem but more a conceptual problem.

I see two options for solving the issue:

**The common and straight-forward solution;**

- add both static library projects into the project of your app
- expand the included projects
- expand the Targets of your app-project
- expand the "Link Binary With Libraries"-Entry
- drag the product files of your library projects (actual libraries) down into that "Link Binary With Libraries"-Entry
- include the header-path to both of your library-projects within your `USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build settings

The next approach is rather unconventional and in most cases just not worth the extra mile. Here comes some explanation before going into the details.

The concept of a static library basically is a bunch of object-files stuffed into one single file (archive). Linking a static library against another static library is rather uncommon - well, to spell it out correctly, impossible.

...but then again, nothing is impossible when it comes to coding ;)...

**The wrapper-library solution;**

- use `ar` to extract all object files from all the libraries you want to combine
- use `ar` to combine all those object files into one big, new library

Comment: The first option looks good to me and in fact I tried going that way but facing issues there. This is how I am doing it: Creating my own static library & header file and putting them inside the Frameworks folder in XCODE of the project where I want to use it. Along with my static library I also put other static libraries directly in Frameworks. These were the libs I wanted to put inside my static lib. Finally in the build settings for this project I am setting "Header Search Path" to the path of these libs.

Comment: After doing the way I described as "The common and straight-forward solution", what is the exact linker error message?

Comment: When compiling I am getting this error: Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyLib", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Many possible issues, NOT a search-path problem. Make sure your libraries are compiling with the "Build Active Architecture Only" set to NO.

Comment: After seeing your edited comment, I a starting to doubt that you actually followed my first option hints... no need to copy anything, just reference the libraries within your project as drafted.

Comment: Now I followed the steps and then I am not able to find the header file of my static library which I have exposed to this application. Any clue?

Comment: My bad, I did not include that step in my draft.. see edited answer.

Comment: Till's answer was useful in my case as well.  My static library had a bunch of C++ wrapped by ObjC.  This caused a bunch of issues with linking in the Application that was using the Static Library (something about undefined symbols).  I just wanted to point out that I had to add the linker flag '-lstdc++'.  To do this in Xcode 4, I went to "Building Settings" -> "Linking" -> "Other Linking Flags".  I hope that helps someone down the line.

Answer (score 2):

ALong with setting up Header Search Path , Try setting up the Other Linkers Flag too..

Go to “Other Linker Flags” under the “Linker” section, and add “-ObjC” and “-all_load” to the list of flags

Hope that works for you,

Comment: Both of those mentioned flags are only useful if the library/ies contain categories on elsewhere implemented classes. Actually, since clang 3 only -ObjC is needed.